# isntall multiple exe inside VS setu project msi?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am trying to add run exe setup inside the msi project. 
what i am trying to do is to run this part of code as Custom action in the project  ?

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.Arguments = arguments;
psi.FileName = Path.Combine(BIPath, EXECUTABLE_NAME);
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
using (Process proc = Process.Start(psi))
{
myInstallContext.LogMessage("before WaitForExit TIME = "+DateTime.Now.ToString());
proc.WaitForExit();
myInstallContext.LogMessage("after WaitForExit TIME = "+DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

but thi part of code never finished ? does there is any other way to do that  in Vistual studio setup project(msi) ?

Comment: You don't say whether you see those log messages or not, so I'm not sure what "never finishes" means, but if that code is in a custom action and is calling another setup.exe that launches an MSI-bases setup then it won't work, because you can't have recursive MSI installs.

Comment: what i meant that never stop that I got this message in the log "before WaitForExit TIME = "+DateTime.Now.ToString() after that it seems stuck , I didnt get the idea for recursive msi . I am running a setup.exe in the custom action inside the running of the msi. what is the recursive step here could you please elaborate ?

Comment: An VS MSI install cannot call an another MSI install from a custom action, that's the issue. I suspect that you are getting error 1618, and the install is silently hanging. It is silent because VS custom actions run with the system account, and therefore will not display in the interactive user's desktop. There aren't many features in VS setups for bundling several MSIs into one setup.

Comment: What I am tring to do to access local exe on the system and run it inside the msi? this is also not accpetable ?